# Need clarification on GridView.getChildCount()

Tags: android, gridview

In my Activity class I have the following code after setContentView() line.

```
gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.splitted_grid);
gridView.setAdapter(new SplittedImageAdapter(this, splittedBitmaps));
gridView.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(splittedBitmaps.size()));
System.out.println(gridView.getChildCount()+" childs");
```

The activity works perfectly and also shows a 3*3 grid with required bitmap images. But the last line shows output as

```
0 childs
```

As per the documentation, the getChildCount() method should show the number of childs that means it should show

```
9 childs
```

Please help me where I am lacking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `gridView.getCount()` method

Comment: Returns
The number of items owned by the Adapter associated with this AdapterView

Comment: It works, but what is the functionality of getChildCount() method?

Comment: Plz Visit http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: The it also should show 9, because all the 9 items are visible to me

Comment: according to http://developer.android(the above url) example it works fine for me,

Answer (score 0):

```
gridview.getCount();
```

returns total number of Images/Bitmap in GridView.